# Increasing Microsoft Azure Blob URL character Limit

Tags: azure, url, blob, cdn

Microsoft Azure Blob URL's character length limit is 1,024 characters. But i want to increase it. How can i increase azure blob URL's character Limit?

Comment: I don't think it is actually possible, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata.

Comment: As @DmitriyPopov mentioned, it is not possible. However I am curious to know more about the use case. Can you edit your question and describe your scenario in more details?

Comment: @GauravMantri , I have developed a kind of file manager in my project using Microsoft Azure blob, where we have a functionality of File/Folder upload, Delete, Copy, Move files and folders And there we support 15 levels of tree structure like you can create upto 15 levels of nested folder So as the level increases blob url of that particular file is also increasing. And now i want to do the same with 30 levels. You can have upto 30 levels of nested folders. so Azure blob url might go beyond 1,024 characters. But right now Azure blob url does not support url character length beyond 1024 chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's impossible.

> A blob name must be at least one character long and cannot be more than 1,024 characters long, for blobs in Azure Storage.

Comment: Ohh.. Anyways. Thank you.